# How Ansible make sure that all the remote nodes are in desired state as per the template/playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Suppose after running a playbook, if someone tried to change the configuration on one/many of the node(s) managed by Ansible. So how does Ansible come to know that one/many of his managed node(s) is/are out of sync and sync it properly to desired state.

I presume we have this in other automation platforms like Chef and Puppet in which the remote agent runs periodically to be in sync with the master server template.

Also what are the best practices to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible doesn't manage anything by itself. It is a tool to automate tasks.
And it is agentless, so no way to get state updates from remote hosts by their will.

You may want to read about [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/tower). Excerpt from features list:

> Set up occasional tasks like nightly backups, periodic configuration remediation for compliance, or a full continuous delivery pipeline with just a few clicks.